# how would you specialize std::greater

Tags: c++, stl

have a

```
std::list<MyBaseClass*> objects;
```

how ( mean a syntax) would you specialize std::greater
for the sort method of std::list

```
template<> class std::greater<MyBaseClass*> {
public:
     bool operator()(const MyBaseClass*& lhs, const MyBaseClass*& rhs) const
     {
         return lhs->get_index() > rhs->get_index();
     }
```

produces the error:

> C2662: 'int MyBaseClass::get_index(void)' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const MyBaseClass' to 'MyBaseClass &'
>   Conversion loses qualifiers

can you explain me the problem please?

Comment: Why do you want to specialize `std::greater`? Implement `operator>` instead for your class or pointer to your class. The error you're seeing is because `get_index` is not a `const` member function.

Comment: your are right, operator > would be prefer.
i'll try to go this way. anyway, thank you for "const" it works too , of course

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your implementation of `eidos::MyBaseClass::get_index()` needs to be marked as "const".